# How do I add a backspace function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to coding and am trying to make a calculator but I'm haveing trouble with a backspace function that I can't do.

```
#this is only part of my code
from tkinter import *
def delete():
    global equation_text
    equation_text = (equation_text+'\b')
    equation_label.set(equation_text)

window = Tk()

equation_text = ''
equation_label = StringVar()

label = Label(window,textvariable=equation_label,font=('Consolas',20),bg='gray',width=29,height=3)
label.pack()

frame = Frame(window,bg='black')
frame.pack()
bequals = Button(frame,text='Del',height=4,width=9,font=35,command=delete).grid(row=3,column=2)
```

This is only part of my code but idk how to make the backspace (delete) function work :\

I tried a few different code segments from my other projects but it didn't work. When you run it, it's not like an entry box. You click the buttons to add numbers and symbols and what I want to happen was for that delete() function to remove the end character.

Comment: The character `'\b'` only has meaning if the software that's rendering it decides to give it meaning. Why not just remove the last character instead adding a special character and rolling dice for whether everything downstream will interpret it the way you want it to?

Answer (score 1):

A different way to look at it is to index the string `equation_text` so that it removes the last character. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
def delete():
    global equation_text
    if equation_text != "":
        equation_text = equation_text[:-1]
    equation_label.set(equation_text)
```

The `equation_text[:-1]` returns all of the characters except for the last in the string. You must also make sure that the string has content before cutting off to prevent errors.

Also, unrelated but you should try to avoid using global variables as it is not best practice and pass parameters instead.